# Creating a function that combines all elements of N number of arrays using apply

Tags: javascript, arguments, prototype, apply, higher-order-functions

I'm practicing higher order functions by actually hard coding what's going on under the hood. I'm stumped by this questions because I have a very limited understanding of how apply() and arguments work.

This is my expected result:

```
mapN([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 2, 2], function(a, b, c) {
  return (a * b) + c;
});
// => [6, 12, 20]

mapN([1, 2, 3], function(x) { return x * x; }) // => [1, 4, 9]
```

I manually coded out a forEach function and a Map function like this ( I know this isn't necessary but I am trying to truly understand what's going on under the hood with HOFs):

```
function each(coll, f) {
  if (Array.isArray(coll)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      f(coll[i], i);
    }
  } else {
    for (var key in coll) {
      f(coll[key], key);
    }
  }
}

function map(array, f) {
  var acc = [];
  each(array, function(element, i) {
    acc.push(f(element, i));
  });
  return acc;
}
```

However, I have no idea where to go from here. How do I use apply and arguments together ? I've spent an hour trying to figure it out ? :

```
function mapN(f){
  var newArray = [];
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments);
  f.apply(newArray, args)
  return newArray;
}
```

Comment: You are using/defining mapN as if it had 3 distinct signatures; which is it?

Comment: @ScottHunter two of them are examples of what if should be handling

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through all the arrays to generate the parameter array that you will use for `apply`:

```
function mapN () {
    var args = Array.from(arguments),                         // arguments passed to `mapN`
        callback = args.pop(),                                // the callback function is the last argument
        result = [];                                          // the result array

    if(!args.length) return result;                           // if there is no arrays passed as arguments, then return the empty array

    for(var i = 0, len = args[0].length; i < len; i++) {      // for each i from 0 to the length of one of the arrays
        var params = args.map(arr => arr[i]);                 // get the i-th element of every array in args to use as parameters to the callback
        result.push(callback.apply(null, params));            // call the callback with the params array and store the result
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Note:** if the arrays could be of different lengths, then you may want to change:

```
len = args[0].length
```

to:

```
len = Math.max.apply(null, args.map(arr => arr.length));
```

so `len` will be equal to the maximum length possible.

**Examples:**

```js
function mapN () {
    var args = Array.from(arguments),
        callback = args.pop(),
        result = [];

    if(!args.length) return result;

    for(var i = 0, len = args[0].length; i < len; i++) {
        var params = args.map(arr => arr[i]);
        result.push(callback.apply(null, params));
    }
    return result;
}

var a = mapN([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 2, 2], function(a, b, c) {
    return (a * b) + c;
});
console.log(a);
// => [6, 12, 20]

var b = mapN([1, 2, 3], function(x) { return x * x; });
console.log(b);
// => [1, 4, 9]
```